# Why did Allah make bad people?

Tags: allah, creation, shaitan

In the Qur'an it says that Shaitan disobeyed Allah and we should make sure we do not fall in the trap of Shaytan as Adam (AS) and Hawwa did. Why doesn't Allah make sure we do not do things which he doesn't want us to do since he has power over all things? I know this is a test and we are supposed to learn from Shaytan's mistake but at the same time I don't understand why Shaytan has been allowed to have so much power. The good people will be rewarded and the bad punished but why did Allah make bad people? Why didn't Allah just make good people?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, it should be pointed out that this question(s) is counted as basic inquiry which indeed can help the people (users) how to behave. In other word, I’d like to express that paying heed to the issue of test will give us a strong patience. Regarding your question as you asked:

> but at the same time I don't understand why Shaytan has been allowed
>   to have so much power  (?)

The answer is that this is completely related to the wisdom or philosophy of Allah. In truth, it seems that:

Whereas Shaytan who has the main role of deceiving the humans, consequently he ought to has such strong power. Otherwise how would be the examination of us? Since human naturally is clean, therefore there is a necessity of something to tempt the human to do the sins, accordingly Allah chose the Satan as that. Although Allah would choose something else instead of Satan if he (Satan) didn’t has such power.

---

Regarding your anther question as you asked

> The good people will be rewarded and the bad punished but why did
>   Allah make bad people?

The answer is that Allah didn’t create bad people. Actually, basically, humans have been created clearly and we cannot accuse Allah why He created bad people. In fact, they have become bad people by themselves based on their free options (which in other word have deceived by Satan (of course according to their free will, not in force)

---

And eventually concerning your last inquiry as you asked

> Why didn't Allah just make good people?

To some extent, its answer is relevant to the previous question and answer. Actually Allah has create all of us clear and in good nature, but they themselves choose the wrong way by their will not Allah created …

---

**Conclusion:**

As you yourself mentioned regarding the issue of TESTING, according to the wisdom of Allah created Satan (although he himself choose the wrong way), then Allah gave him a high power to be the means of testing the humans that who will select the right path or not. In the meanwhile, as another significant point:the testing of Human would be meaningless if all of people were good, on the other hand Allah would take them to the paradise directly instead of ... (Note: I solely explain it from an aspect quite briefly due to...

I finally indeed appreciate you for asking such significant basic question which can be the question of any people. God Bless You.

---

As some related matters, I recommend you to read the following links:

[www.islamquest.net in English](http://www.islamquest.net/en/archive/question/fa883) / [Arabic](http://www.islamquest.net/ar/archive/question/fa883) / and [Arabic 2](http://www.islamquest.net/ar/archive/question/fa5754)

---

**Reference:**

[www.shia-news.com](http://www.shia-news.com/fa/news/51979/%DA%86%D8%B1%D8%A7-%D8%AE%D8%AF%D8%A7-%D9%85%D8%A7-%D8%B1%D8%A7-%D8%A7%D9%85%D8%AA%D8%AD%D8%A7%D9%86-%D9%85%DB%8C-%DA%A9%D9%86%D8%AF)

Answer (score 0):

Allah (swt) didn't make good or bad people, he gave us free will. That is why we're among one of his best creations. We were granted free will and the ability to choose from right or wrong. (And Allah knows best)

Comment: Yh but why does Allah allow us to do bad things as well as good?

Comment: Again, because we have free will. Which means we control ourselves. Whether good or bad. Also, Allah made heaven and hell because of that partly. If Allah gave us the ability to only do good then we wouldn't have free will and there would be No use for earth and this test. Allah gave us this test as a chance to get into his heaven.

Comment: ...my question is why did Allah (swt) create human that he will throw in hell? Why not only create those that he will throw in jannah? And yes we have free will but still everything happens by the will of Allah.

Comment: God knows the future of what the free-will creatures choose. Free will does not stop becoming free because God knows what will happen. For example, I know that my child will choose to eat chocolate cake over a bowl full of stinking dead mice. If I were to set them both before my child, it is safe to say that she will not eat the dead mice. Knowing this is not taking away the freedom of my child since she is freely choosing one over the other. Likewise, for God to know what a person will choose does not mean that the person has no freedom to make the choice. It simply means that God knows what

Comment: We will choose. And what would be the point of earth and this dunya if Allah let only the people who will go to jannah on here? What would be the point of earth? Just because they are going to hell and Allah knows it, does not mean don't create them in the first place because he knows that. That's not fair, that's not how the world works

Comment: So why does He make them? Just so He has some to punish too? I don't get it. And everything happens with Allah's will so it Allah's will that they do not get enough good deeds?

Comment: @Imaan That's a weak example. You don't know for absolute certainty that she won't eat the bowl of dead mice, you only predict based on what you know about the person. You are not all knowing, God is, so you cannot say for 100% certainty what she will do. God can. There is a big difference. The person makes the choice but God has written what the choice will be. So how is that free will?

Comment: @Zohal You're asking some great questions and you're getting some pretty weak answers. Keep soul searching and never stop questioning ideas. The actual answer to your question is -  **We do not know**. We are living within the realms of our universe. God is not bound to time and existence as we are. So we are only capable of thinking so much. We do not know why God created us is the real answer. Most people try and give their own reasons but most of them contradict God's characteristics. God has no needs, wants, desires, requirements so if he is perfect then why create? We just don't know.

Comment: This resembles the Qadariyyah thinking

Answer (score 0):

You asked a very good question. One that requires thinking outside the box and questioning the general acceptance.

The actual answer to your question is - **We do not know**.

We are living within the realms of our universe. God is not bound to time and existence as we are. So we are only capable of thinking so much. We do not know why God created us is the real answer. Most people try and give their own reasons but most of them contradict God's characteristics. God has no needs, wants, desires, requirements so if he is perfect then why create?

In Islam, everything is pre-destined by God:

> “No calamity befalls on the earth or in yourselves but it is inscribed in the Book of Decrees (Al‑Lawh Al‑Mahfooz) before We bring it into existence. Verily, that is easy for Allaah - [al-Hadeed 57:22]

This indicates that whatever will occur in humanity has already been decided and written before we came into existence.

Your question about why God created bad people is a question which nobody can justifiably answer without trying to divert the question onto other related aspects of creation.

Let me give you an example. God knew that there will be this little boy who will grow up, take charge of Germany and kill millions and millions of Jews. God knew this will happen before he decided to create. Therefore God is the creator of both good and evil. So by that we can conclude that God is the ultimate creator of everything. So then the question arises, **WHY?**. Why did this perfect God who does not desire, require, want, need anything decide to create?

Some people would argue life is a test for heaven and hell. But how can it be a test if God is the one who has decided the outcome of eternity? What is he testing? It cannot be human choice because ultimately we are not given one. Can he be testing his own powers? That would indicate imperfection.

[Moses Maimonides](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_from_free_will) summed it up best:

> "Does God know or does He not know that a certain individual will be good or bad? If thou sayest 'He knows', then it necessarily follows that the man is compelled to act as God knew beforehand how he would act, otherwise God's knowledge would be imperfect.…"

Anyone who argues God needs, wants, requires or desires anything then that would immediately contradict God's attributes and would indicate imperfection. Those are human characteristics, which is why we're imperfect.

**Shi'a belief:**

> God has not set a definite course for human history. Instead, God may alter the course of human history as is seen to be fit.
>   Shiite states that matters relating to the human destiny is of two kinds: definite and indefinite. To explain the definitive one, Shiite argues that God has definite power over the whole of existence, however, whenever He wills, He can replace a given destiny with another one; and that is what is called indefinite destiny. - (*[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predestination_in_Islam#cite_note-17)*).

Overall, we can argue many reasons as to why God made us in the first place, regardless of whether they were good or bad. But we definitely cannot put our fingers on this one. We simply don't know enough.

Sometimes saying we don't know something is better than fighting a lost battle.

Oh and by the way.. that little boy's name was Hitler.

Comment: **<comments deleted>** Comments are intended for constructive criticism and seeking clarification, not for argument and debate or extended discussion of tangential points.

Answer (score 0):

> Why did Allah make bad people?

Of course if the world is filled with all good people it will be boring, that doesn't mean you have to do evil. :D

The short answer is that Allah created various kinds of humans with all kinds of shapes, traits, ethnicities and races so that we humans can get to know each other and learn about this vast knowledge of Allah.

Sorry for my english, i am still learning

Answer (score 0):

About hell , heaven , bad and good , it's all about the test.

We are given question paper , we have pencils or pen and we have erasers too . Now , how to use it is our choice. We can write correct answer and erase it ( good deeds erased by bad ones ) or we can write wrong answers and erase it ( bad deeds erased by good ones ).
The result depends on that but that doesn't mean that you won't be allowed to use any one of these two equipments in the test , either write everything wrong at once or write everything good at once. It's a test , what you do , is your choice but the result depends on your choice.
He set us free in this world.

A small revision test has already been taken before we were even born ( our souls are asked if we believe in Allah or not by the angels and if we say yes , we are born as muslims but if we say no , we are born as non muslims ) Of course who is born as muslim will believe in Allah but if his soul already denied then Allah sent him in a non muslim family but he still has a chance if he wants to believe in Allah or not. Believing in Allah isn't for Allah , it's for us.

An art piece is best when belongs to the original creator rather than any other creator. Mona Lisa must have not been that famous if it wasn't for Leonardo Di'Vinci.

Also , if you think that all muslims will go to heaven and all non muslims to hell , no. Allah says that our one good deed can erase all our bad deeds and our one bad deed can erase our all good deeds. Those muslims who think that they pray and always remember Allah and will go to heaven , they are too confident. If they ever hurt someone or because of them if someone ever cried or felt bad , he might not go to heaven.
If someone doesn't pray and all that but always help the needy and do good deeds , he can go to heaven too.

I agree with these two statements  :

" The answer is that Allah didn’t create bad people. Actually, basically, humans have been created clearly and we cannot accuse Allah why He created bad people. In fact, they have become bad people by themselves based on their free options. "

" Allah (swt) didn't make good or bad people, he gave us free will. That is why we're among one of his best creations. We were granted free will and the ability to choose from right or wrong. "

(An example that I liked from previous comment but I changed it a bit)

For example : if there's a shop of chocolates and a shop of vegetables in front of a child , I know , by human nature , the child would choose chocolate , which tastes good but it's result isn't good , vegetables doesn't tastes good but it's going to keep him healthy. Some will realise , some won't. I didn't make those chocolate shops. I won't want that child to eat chocolate but that doesn't mean that I will remove those shops from there. Even if I am the president of that country or whatever , the humans are set free , whatever they do is with their own choice.

Also , not everyone will go to heaven or hell. Praying for Allah starts after the age of puberty so , what about those who die before puberty ? They never prayed , where will they go ?

There is not only heaven or hell , there's one more place , Araf ( I am not 100 % sure if the spelling is correct or not , I heard it a while ago ) the righteous non muslims will go there , live a temporary life there , as the proof of Allah will be already in front of their eyes , they will know that Islam was the right religion to follow on earth but because they never did anything wrong , they will be given a second chance , they will live a temporary life in Araf where they will pray for Allah and after that period end , they will be sent to heaven.

So , no , not all muslims will go to heaven and all non muslims to hell. Same with the ones who died before hitting puberty. They too will live a temporary life.

But this is for those who lived their life without knowing what is there in Islam , what all it says and were always interested in their religion.
And as we can see , it's very rare now. Everyone is interested in knowing about Islam and even after knowing pretty much everything an average muslim would know , they still deny that Islam is the right religion. If they never did that , they would go to Araf but unfortunately , they ruined it themselves.

It's like , we know murders are happening in the world but if we never saw one , how can we save them ? But if one was happening in front of us and yet we ignored , then it is our fault that we didn't stop that , probably because we were too scared to lost our life and might not even.

We know what is in Islam , we know what all it teaches but still we decide to see its bad side that happen to be created by humans not Islam.

Let me tell you one more thing that I was taught. Just like different angels , Satan , who used to worship Allah , was also there. When Allah created his first human being , Hazrat Adam ( peace be upon him ) he told the Angels to bow in front of him ( as he was going to start the human life ) so the angels did but Satan denied , said that , I'm made up of fire and he's made up of clay , why would I bow against him ? I'm more powerful but it was Allah's order , he had to yet he denied and was no longer allowed to live in heaven. Arrogance increased , he tried to challenged Allah that till the day of judgement , he will try to distract the human kind ( because he was already against humans being superior ) so , Allah said , do it if you want but the one who knows the creator of everything will never get distracted , he will always worship me and put me above everything and I will give him reward for his this act , in this world and afterwards as well.

So , no one is born a bad person , we get distracted by the bad things ( which looks good just like chocolate looks much better than vegetables but we know what is better ) and forget our creator , Allah.

If you make a art piece and someone steal it or claim that this was not made by you or anyone in that place , it just happen to come here , you will feel angry that you made it but that won't decrease your abilities. You're still what you're even if your art piece got stolen or claimed to appear here out of nowhere. Same in this case , he made us but if we think that no , this is the right Creator (any other God ) or there is not any creator so of course it won't decrease his abilities , instead we will be the one to get it's result. He never chose us to be bad , he just chose us to live and remember him but it's us who chose it and we will be responsible for it in the afterlife too.

Answer (score -3):

Who said that Allah made it? Please just one minute think wise. Children of bad parents now are best people in town and otherwise. If I force you to do worst thing, do you accept? Many of questions are wrong because we think every question we made is correct. Sometimes answer can be find in question. People has choice. God bless you.

Comment: I don't understand what your are saying but Allah has made everything. I know the children of bad people are not always bad and that is not relate to my question.

Comment: I am so sorry that my answer was not related to your question.because changing is easy when you are just thinking but in real life is different. Changing and monitoring that changes is the only important thing in this world. by reading Quaran we have seen many people came but the result of them was negative. Some of them changes but at the end they return to negative. Bani Israiel Story.

Comment: How you can identify bad people or bad people? If bad people does not be then good people cant be identified. You can learn good things by many mistakes. Its like giving me negative vote cant stop me to find the true. Why god? You want to find answer of question which only he knows. Others try answer but you igonre because its not like you want. Thanks

Comment: That is a good point that you cannot identify good unless there is bad to compare it with however my question is that why does Allah let us do thing  which He know will anger Him or things which He dislikes? For example why does Allah let us steal or kill? Why does Allah not stop us doing these things instead of punishing us later? Allah created us and is able to control us so why does He not use His power to make sure we only do that which makes Him happy? Our purpose is to worship Allah then why doesn't Allah only allow us to worship him and not do anything else?